# How can i call the fields of a foreignkey in the template html django

Tags: python, django, templates, model, jinja2

how can i call the movie_details and actor fields or variables from the MovieDetail class in the model.py to my html template. Thank you very much i am new to django will be loving solutions from here.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

class MoviePosters(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "pics")
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length = 150)


class MovieSection(models.Model):
    image_side = models.ImageField(upload_to = "pics")
    title_side = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    movie_link = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Section"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_side


class MovieDetails(models.Model):
    movie_section = models.ForeignKey(MovieSection, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    movie_details = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    actors = models.CharField(max_length= 200)

    class meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "movie_details"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie_details
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import MoviePosters, MovieSection,Ticket, MovieDetails

def single_link(request, single_link):
    movie_details = MovieSection.objects.get(pk=single_link)   
    return render(request, "reviewmovie.html", {"part_ones": movie_details})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're interested in getting the data from the MovieDetails model so consider running a query that filters for what you're looking for within that model. Something like:

movie_details = MovieDetails.objects.get(movie_section__pk=single_link)

Comment: Yh it worked. I will love it if you suggest books or YouTube video for me to learn more and be a better Django developer

Answer (score 0):

set a related name option (related_name='moviesection'):

```
    movie_section = models.ForeignKey(MovieSection, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='moviesection')
```

and then you will be able to access MovieDetails with:

```
movie_details.moviesection.all()
```

Also, rename the movie_details in your single_link function as its name is the same as in the model and might lead to confusion.